# How i can map entity whit composite key mvc 4 entity framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the next problem i am trying map this entity model but when mi app call the entity this entity has not related whit the other class and any o you data, i have the code:

```
public MedicamentoMap()
{
            // primaryKey
            this.HasKey(m => m.Id);

            // propiedades
            this.ToTable("Medicamento");
            this.Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("MedicamentoID");
            this.Property(m => m.Descripcion).HasColumnName("Descripcion");

            //Relaciones


            //map

            this.HasMany(c => c.Presentaciones)
                .WithMany(m=>m.Medicamentos)
                .Map (mc =>
                {
                   mc.ToTable("MedicamentoPresentacion");
                   mc.MapLeftKey("MedicamentoID");
                   mc.MapRightKey("PresentacionID");
               });
         }`
```

my tables
[are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Fi3.jpg)

Comment: Although English is not your native language I think you can do better than "any o you data". I don't understand the problem.

Comment: sorry mi problem is when i map my entities for example i have 3 tables many to many in my third table i have a composite key how i can map is my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map one to many composite key Entity framework 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480244/map-one-to-many-composite-key-entity-framework-5)

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in EF, but I had a problem before while using a composite key in a junction table in my EF ORM.  When I gave it to foreign keys, it did not like it, so I changed it to a composite key and it still gave me trouble.  The easiest solution I found was to create a primary key, even though it was unused, and EF established the relationships correctly with the foreign keys.  Give that a try and I bet it will work.  Add a primary key to the table and reduce the composite key to just normal foreign keys.  EF loves single primary keys.